# Switching step-down voltage regulator gives lower output-current than input current

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, switching, loss

I'm currently trying to build a photovolatik cell -> DC Converter -> Battery-management-System. In the early stages of the build I was trying to use the adjustable voltage regulator alongside of a potentiometer. I plugged in a solar cell with about 12 V inputvoltage and the outload was a battery pack (don't worry; just discharged NiMH-batteries, shouldn't be an issue if I slightly overcharge them.
Adjusting the potentiometer (R2) to get closer to the Maximum Power Point, I achieved an input current of 157 mA, while the output-current was just 150 mA. Input voltage was about 8V, while output voltage was never higher than 5V. Where do I lose the current?
[image: LM2575]

Here are the components I used:

C_in = C_out = 330 muF

C_ff = 100 muF

L1 = 330 muH

R1 = 1kOhm

R2 = 0....200kOhm

D1 = SB160 (Schottky-diode)

Where is the error in my build? I'm thankful for every answer!

Kind regards

Comment: The extra current is supposed to "come from" D1. You are measuring the current in series with the load, right, not in series with the chip's output pin?

Comment: I measured in series after the regulated output. The load consists of two batteries. (approx. 2.8-3.2V)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Input: 8V, 157 mA

Output: 5V, 150 mA

Efficiency: 60%

This is not surprising. You're using a very old DC-DC chip with a high idle current (5-10mA), a BJT switch, and it is not a synchronous buck.

[image]

The bipolar switch transistor saturation voltage is specified at 1.16V typical, so you're already losing 14.5% of your input voltage and efficiency there. The diode should have about 0.5V on it, which is another 10% efficiency loss. The idle current will consume up to 5% of input power. So we're starting with a theoretical maximum of about 70%, and we haven't even added the losses in the inductor and capacitors yet.

If the caps are general purpose high-ESR models, then another 10% loss is not surprising, and the 60% efficiency checks out.

The problem here is that input voltage is close to output voltage, so the switch conducts at a high duty cycle, which means its high saturation voltage really hurts. Also, output voltage is pretty low, so the diode's voltage drop also hurts.

If you want higher efficiency, you need a more modern chip, a synchronous buck with two MOSFET switches, low-ESR caps, and the inductor has to be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply!
I've also tried it with a different one (MP2307) and got a really good efficiency after all. I swapped its potentiometer  with a digital potentiometer (MCP 4151: https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/MCP4151_MIC.pdf ) with the same values but also lost some points on efficiency compared to a normal potentiometer. Does anyone probably see any reasoing behind that?

Comment: Good! No idea why the digipot lowers efficiency. Maybe its capacitance makes it unstable or something...